# Machine learning code fill up local disk usage

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

when i run code with convolution-neural-network, my local disk memory always fill up for unknown reason. actually it takes about 10 GB but i can't find the reason and folder. what is the problem?

Comment: Hi Dan! You talking about your hard drive or your RAM? Nonetheless, during training you network, much more memory is required than the size of the model. Beside the model and the dataset, the inputs and outputs of all layers are kept in memory, until they have been used in the backpropagation step to calculate the gradients. You could try to use lower precission (e.g. float16 instead of float32 or mixed precission see: https://medium.com/@SaschaKirch/speed-up-your-tensorflow-training-with-mixed-precision-on-gpu-tpu-acf4c8c0931c) or reduce the batch size.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try that solution. :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.